# onRequest vs onCall returning null

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Please help me figure out the difference in return behaviour between the onCall and onRequest google functions below.

- onCall, the problem: returns null on all returns, except at the first return (as commented below). The db entries and rest of the code works fine. Just no returns problem.
- onRequest, returns perfectly fine on every return. The db entries and rest of the code also works fine.

Both as you will see compare the same, but I just can't seem to get it to work at all. Any advice on how to get my returns to work for the onCall (and structure it better) would be much appreciated.

I am keen on sticking with async await (as opposed to a promise). Using Node.js 12. I am calling the onCall in Flutter, don't know if that is relevant for the question.

The onCall:

```
  exports.applyUserDiscount = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) return {message: "Authentication Required!", code: 401};

  const uid = context.auth.uid;
  const discountCode = data["discountCode"];
  const cartTotal = data["cartTotal"];

  try {
    return await db.collection("discountCodes").where("itemID", "==", discountCode).limit(1).get()
        .then(async (snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.empty) {
            return "doesNotExist"; // The only return that works.
          } else { // Everything else from here onwards returns null.
            snapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
              if (doc.data().redeemed == true) {
                return "codeUsed";
              } else {
                const newCartTotal = cartTotal - doc.data().discountAmount;
                if (newCartTotal < 0) {
                  return "lessThanTotal";
                } else {
                  doc.ref.update({
                    redeemed: true,
                    uid: uid,
                    redeemDate: fireDateTimeNow,
                  });
                  await db.collection("userdata").doc(uid).set({
                    cartDiscount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-doc.data().discountAmount),
                  }, {merge: true});
                  return doc.data().discountAmount.toString();
                }
              }
            });
          }
        });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error:" + error);
    return "error";
  }
});
```

The onRequest:

```
exports.applyUserDiscount = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

  const uid = req.body.uid;
  const discountCode = req.body.discountCode;
  const cartTotal = req.body.cartTotal;

  try {
    return await db.collection("discountCodes").where("itemID", "==", discountCode).limit(1).get()
        .then(async (snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.isempty) {
            res.send("doesNotExist");
          } else {
            snapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
              if (doc.data().redeemed == true) {
                res.send("codeUsed");
              } else {
                const newCartTotal = cartTotal - doc.data().discountAmount;
                if (newCartTotal < 0) {
                  res.send("lessThanTotal");
                } else {
                  doc.ref.update({
                    redeemed: true,
                    uid: uid,
                    redeemDate: fireDateTimeNow,
                  });
                  await db.collection("userdata").doc(uid).set({
                    cartDiscount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-doc.data().discountAmount),
                  }, {merge: true});
                  res.send(doc.data().discountAmount.toString());
                }
              }
            });
          }
        });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.send("error");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several points to be noted when looking at your code(s):

- You should not use `async/await` within a `forEach` loop. The problem is that the callback passed to `forEach()` is not being awaited, see more explanations [here](https://www.hacksparrow.com/javascript/foreach-in-promise-async-function.html) or [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404). **HOWEVER**, in your case you don't need to loop over the [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) **since it contains only one doc**. You can use the [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) property which return an array of all the documents in the `QuerySnapshot` and take the first (and unique) element.
- You mix-up `then()` with `async/await`, which is not recommended.
- I would advise to [throw exceptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) for the "error" cases, like `doesNotExist`, `codeUsed` or `lessThanTotal` but it's up to you to choose. The fact that, for example, the `lessThanTotal` case is an error or a standard business case is debatable... So if you prefer to send a "text" response, I would advise to encapsulate this response in a Object with one property: in your front-end the response will always have the same format.

---

So, the following should do the trick. Note that I send back on object with a `response` element, including for the cases that could be considered as errors. As said above you could throw an exception in these cases.

```
exports.applyUserDiscount = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) ... //See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors

    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    const discountCode = data["discountCode"];
    const cartTotal = data["cartTotal"];

    try {
        const snapshot = await db.collection("discountCodes").where("itemID", "==", discountCode).limit(1).get();

        if (snapshot.empty) {

            //See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors

        } else {
            const uniqueDoc = snapshot.docs[0];

            if (uniqueDoc.data().redeemed == true) {
                return { response: "codeUsed" };
            } else {
                const newCartTotal = cartTotal - uniqueDoc.data().discountAmount;
                if (newCartTotal < 0) {
                    return { response: "lessThanTotal" };
                } else {
                    await uniqueDoc.ref.update({   // See await here!!
                        redeemed: true,
                        uid: uid,
                        redeemDate: fireDateTimeNow,
                    });
                    await db.collection("userdata").doc(uid).set({
                        cartDiscount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-uniqueDoc.data().discountAmount),
                    }, { merge: true });
                    return {
                        response: uniqueDoc.data().discountAmount.toString()
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error:" + error);
        return "error";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your concise answer and the advice, it works perfectly now. I turned them all into exceptions, except for when the discount amount is returned, works great! Much appreciated  .